# Why we use -adien- / -atrien- infixes if we need to indicate double bond positions with numbers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

For exemple: instead of Buta-1,3-diene why we don't use but-1,3-ene. In my mind, there would be no confusion when using the nomenclature that way because we use one number to indicate the position of each bond. Is there any particular reason for the use of these infixes?